# vertica copy command with null value for Integer

Tags: vertica

Is there any empty character i can put into the csv in order to put a null value

into an integer column

without using the ",X" pattern?

i.e. (X is a value and the first one is null)

Comment: I don't know the platform you're talking about, but the general approach to this would be to literally put nothing in the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a file /tmp/file.csv like this:

```
2016-01-10,100,abc
2016-02-21,,def
2017-01-01,300,ghi
```

and a target table defined as follows:

```
create table t1 ( dt date, id integer, txt char(10));
```

Then, the following command will insert NULL into "id" for the second column (the one having dt='2016-02-21'):

```
copy t1 from '/tmp/file.csv' delimiter ',' direct abort on error;
```

Now, if you want to use a **special string to identify NULL values** in your input file, let's say 'MYNULL':

```
2016-01-10,100,abc
2016-02-21,MYNULL,def
2017-01-01,300,ghi
```

Then... you have to run copy COPY this way:

```
copy t1 from '/tmp/file.csv' delimiter ',' null 'MYNULL' direct abort on error;
```